# Turkish character problem in aes encryption algorithm

Tags: python, aes

own aes encryption module using python language
I'm trying to write, but in the subBytes section, I could not find how to process data larger than 8 bits in hexadecimal value. How can I subBytes data like 0xc3a7 for example?

I need to find the equivalent of the data in the 4x4 matrix from the lookup table and write it instead. For example, I have to replace data 0x19 with data in column 9 of row 1 of the lookup table. but what should I do if the data is long data like 0xc3a7?

Comment: Forget changing the subBytes, transfers your encoding into bytes, then feed the bytes. Encryption algorithms are designed to work on bits,bytes,words,etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you require assistance and want people to help you, please consider providing an example of your code such that the problem can be better understood.